# DIY solder mask + toner transfer

Tags: pcb-fabrication, solder-mask

so I've gotten a decent 1 layer toner transfer process down and I'm looking to add some nice touches to it before I move on to trying 2 layer boards.

Anybody know how to do a nice silkscreen layer or solder mask layer with toner transfer?

Thanks

Comment: You need a solder mask for wave soldering, and that doesn't agree with DIY!

Comment: @stevenvh Sure that's when you **need** a solder mask, but that's certainly not the only time you might **want** a solder mask.

Comment: @JGord - aesthetics? :-)

Comment: @stevenvh of course =)      it also prevents accidental shorts during real sloppy soldering

Comment: If you keep adding complicated steps to the DIY process, pretty soon getting boards commercially made start to look pretty good.  Then you not only get solder mask and silkscreen, but plated thru holes.

Comment: PTH has been managed with DIY PCBs, as well.

Comment: @Olin The first link in Leon's answer shows a great way of doing mechanical vias. Apparently PTHs can be done with rivets... When would you ever need PTHs over vias?

Comment: I meant real PTH, but rivets or wire work quite well.

Comment: I tried rivets in the past, but they didn't quite fit in the 0.1mm space I had underneath SMT ICs.

Comment: I try to avoid vias under SMT ICs with my home-made PCBs.

Comment: Solder masks help protect against accidental short circuits, and protect the copper. Architectural fixtures such as copper or brass lamps and door hardware get a clear coat, so why not your copper traces?  *Love the warm glow of copper? Keep it copper with Everbrite coatings!* http://www.everbrite.net/copper.htm   LOL. :)

Comment: "If you keep adding complicated steps to the DIY process, pretty soon getting boards commercially made start to look pretty good." -- I always hate it when people say things like this.. DIY isn't about "cheap" to many of us, it's about the process and creating things yourself. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A technique for applying solder mask is described here:

http://retromaster.wordpress.com/pcb-making/

You should join the Homebrew PCB group, this sort of thing gets discussed there all the time:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/Homebrew_PCBs/

I found the technique mentioned above by searching their messages. Techniques for applying silk screen come up frequently, as well.

I use the photo-etch technique, which makes things like solder mask and silk screen much easier than with toner transfer. I don't bother with them, though.

Comment: Wow, that first link is real impressive. As for the homebrew pcbs group... Am I stupid or is the search functionality miserable?

Comment: It's a Yahoo group, the search facility is rather poor. Some of the groups have the posts archived elsewhere, with better searching.